# Why does JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator implement IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I realised that I can get an enumerator from `ArrayEnumerator`, which itself is already an `IEnumerator` Neither `List`, nor `Array` has this. I'm curious what's the reason for implementing `IEnumerable` on an `IEnumerator` ?
**I am not using GetEnumerator() calls, I'm aware of foreach, I'm curious about what kind of requirement or use case for an enumerator would lead to this design choice** It was not considered necessary for the most commonly used array and list types, so why is it in place for the `ArrayEnumerator` type?
Here's the linqpad code that demonstrates what I am talking about:

```
var myArr = new int[] {1,2,3};
var enumerator1 = myArr.GetEnumerator(); //no more .GetEnumerator()

var myLst = new List<int>();
myLst.Add(1); myLst.Add(2);
myLst.GetEnumerator(); //no more .GetEnumerator()

var jsonDoc = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse("[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]");
System.Text.Json.JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator arrEnum = jsonDoc.RootElement.EnumerateArray();
System.Text.Json.JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator arrEnum1 = arrEnum.GetEnumerator();

foreach (var el in arrEnum){
    el.Dump("0");
}

foreach(var el in arrEnum1){
    el.Dump("1");
}
```

Comment: That's not a general purpose Enumerator class, although nothing prevents a class from implementing both `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` if that serves a purpose. JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator isn't a generic enumerator, it's part of System.Text.Json and implements `IEnumerator<JsonElement>` and `IEnumerable<JsonElement>` only. Comparing it to List or Array is comparing apples to oranges. You can check the [actual source to see how it's implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator.cs#L16)

Comment: If it didn't have a `GetEnumerator` method, you wouldn't be able to use a `foreach` on it. That doesn't sound useful... Would you want `JsonElement` to have a `GetEnumerator` method instead? That doesn't look logical IMO.

Comment: STJ is built for performance and using one class instead of several saves one object allocation per complex element. If you check the source you'll see that ArrayEnumerator uses an index into the parent element's list of elements. Only a nested class can do that. The constructor is internal, so only STJ classes can use that enumerator

Comment: Why are you using an enumerator directly anyway? Why not use `foreach`? You rarely see any applications use enumerators directly. You only see that in specialized libraries like MoreLinq, System.Text.Json, System.Linq.Async or LINQ itself, that implement custom enumeration operations or have specialized performance requirements

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the code above runs just fine, so both enumerators are usable. I'm curious about the use case for an enumerator being an enumerator. I.e. what's the requirement that led to this design?

Comment: I answered that and even linked to the source file. There's no reason to use separate classes but there *can* be a cost. STJ was built to eliminate allocations so allocating 1 object instead of 2 is always a gain, especially in a class that's called thousands of times in an application. For more specifics you'll have to check the GitHub repo. STJ is open source and the development issues and design decisions are documented in Github

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK I think I see it now. Do you mean it is a consequence of IEnumerable and IEnumerator being implemented on the same type to decrease GC pressure? i.e. there is no use case, but it is a result of implementing the same interface on the concrete class and returning the class itself leading to the caller ending up with the original Ienumerable. That explains it. Care to write an answer so that I can accept it? Happy to write one but you answered it, not I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the comment from @panagiotis-kanavos. Briefly: there is no design decision to use an `IEnumerator<T>` as an `IEnumerable<T>` The reason for `ArrayEnumerator`'s `GetEnumerator()` returning both the expected `IEnumerator<T>` **and** an `IEnumerable<T>` is because it is returning itself specifically, i.e. the `ArrayEnumerator` type, which supports both interfaces. The type implements both interfaces to lessen the number of allocations.

I personally suspect the reason to return the type itself rather than the interface is to signify the fact that the type implements both inferfaces, but I'm not sure about that one. Nonetheless, the answer to my question is that this is a consequence of a decision made for performance reasons, not related to reusing an `IEnumerator<T>` as an `IEnumerable<T>`